# Power Query custom function, no incrementation made, everything is either 1/0: why?

Tags: indexing, powerbi, increment, powerquery, m

I am extremely frustrated with a file and a custom column. I do not understand what is not working.

I have a file with one column, ID which I am trying to continue based on the values in a column called Geography.

Geography contains countries and regions.

Italy and UK are my two countries.
Regions are marked with a letter:
- ItalyZ designate a region, ItalyB another region.
- UKM designate a region, UKY designates another region.

I have another column called "ID" with code which matching a country (AB equal italy, BC equal UK).

Range of number designates the occurences of events in the region.
Region Z in italy starts at 0 and ends at 4000
Region B in italy starts above 3000 and ends at 6000

Region M in UK starts at 0 and ends at 5000
Region Y in UK starts above 5000 and ends at 9999

I am trying to logically continue my column with the matching country codes (AB, BC...) and the occurrences number.

Here is a description of the data:

```
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|    
  |      Nap            |       Wourf      |       ID         |      Geography      |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |     Uofvduba        |     Uofvduba     |    AB0000        |        ItalyZ       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |      OIofvduba      |     OIofvduba    |    AB4041        |       ItalyB        |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |   gttrg             |      gttrg       |    BC0000        |        UKY          |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |      VDba           |     VDba         |    BC4001        |         UKM         |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |      SVuDba         |      NULL        |   NULL           |      ItalyZ         |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |      SnoVDGGuba     |     NULL         |   NULL           |           ItalyZ    |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |      SFSnouba       |       NULL       |    NULL          |         UKY         |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |      GDSnouba       |       NULL       |   NULL           |        UKY          |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

I have the following M code and I do not understand why the output of my custom column simply is 1 or 0 instead of adding one to the last highest occurrence:

```
 #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Snouba", type text}, {"Snurp", type text}, {"Nabou", type number}, {"Favou 1", Int64.Type}, {"Favou 2", Int64.Type}, {"Favou 3", Int64.Type}, {"Favou 4", Int64.Type}, {"fsfsfsrewrw", type text}, {"Lamfew", type number}, {"gergerer", type text}, {"FERGT", type text}, {"SuperSum", type text}, {"GDGD", type text}, {"Geography", type text}, {"ID", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Prefix", each Text.Middle([ID],0,2), type text),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Number", each Number.FromText(Text.Middle([ID],2,5))),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Number AB", each if [Prefix] = "AB" then [Number] else 0),
    #"Added Conditional Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "Number BC", each if [Prefix] = "BC" then [Number] else 0),
    #"Added Conditional Column2" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column1", "Number AB range below 4000", each if [Number AB] < 3999 then [Number AB] else 0),
    #"Added Conditional Column3" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column2", "Number AB range above 4000", each if [Number AB] > 3999 then [Number AB] else 0),
    #"Added Conditional Column4" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column3", "Number BC range above 5000", each if [Number BC] > 4999 then [Number BC] else 0),
    #"Added Conditional Column5" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column4", "Number BC range below 5000", each if [Number BC] > 4999 then [Number BC] else 0),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Conditional Column5",{"Snouba", "Snurp", "Nabou", "Favou 1", "Favou 2", "Favou 3", "Favou 4", "fsfsfsrewrw", "Lamfew", "gergerer", "FERGT", "SuperSum", "GDGD", "Prefix", "Number", "Number AB", "Number BC", "Number AB range below 4000", "Number AB range above 4000", "Number BC range above 5000", "Number BC range below 5000", "Index", "Geography", "ID"}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Sum", each if [Geography] = "UKM" then [Number AB range below 4000] + 1 
else if [Geography] = "UKY" then [Number AB range above 4000] + 1 
else if [Geography] = "ItalyB" then [Number BC range above 5000]
else [Number BC range below 5000] + 1)
in
    #"Added Custom2"
```

I added the following custom column, but it is not working either, with an incrementation for the higest number which repeats itself over and over the whole column:

```
if #"Changed Type1"[Geography] = "UKM" then List.Max(#"Changed Type1"[Number AB range below 4000]) + 1 
else if #"Changed Type1"[Geography] = "UKY" then List.Max(#"Changed Type1"[Number AB range above 4000]) + 1 
else if #"Changed Type1"[Geography] = "ItalyB" then List.Max(#"Changed Type1"[Number BC range above 5000]) + 1
else List.Max(#"Changed Type1"[Number BC range below 5000]) + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing operations on the previous step and expecting them to be iteratively applied like an Excel column referencing the previous row.

For example, in the following the `List.Max` applied to the previous step is a constant value and isn't dependent on what row you are calling it from in the current step:

```
List.Max(#"Changed Type1"[Number AB range below 4000]) + 1
```

(Ask yourself why you would expect this to return different max values for different rows.)

---

The M language of these queries isn't designed to operate recursively like you're expecting. That said, it's still possible, just not the way you are thinking.

This is the "Why" you are asking. For something that does work, I'd suggest writing a new question referencing this one but with a simplified example for clarity and ease of answering (there are too many distracting details here).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I will try to ask the "how". If you can provide some pointers on improvements for the "how", I will be extremely greatfull, because I am slowly loosing my mind.

Comment: Try to create an example that is as simple as possible while still getting at the core of what you are trying to do. Be sure to specify what you expect the end result to be. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you. By the way, I have seen a several tutorials (and tried to understand) on the notion of running total which seems more or less close to my issue, and this really leads to the question of my a cell cannot be refereed to as a cell in Power Query. I tried reading information on functional language and the specification of M. I am trying to understand why the setup of M (or DAX if I understand correctly) is constructed this way.

Comment: It really is a shift in thinking compared to loops. DAX and SQL have similar logic where operations are done on columns rather than looping through elements. It's definitely annoying when trying to do things recursively but works beautifully for the things it's designed to do well.

Comment: But would it be possible to have a system with both? Or "swith mode" in a way?

Comment: M does do both, just not necessarily with equal ease. Every language has its tradeoffs.

Comment: Ok. Thank you extremely strongly. I created a new "how" question that I hope is much better formulated.

Comment: @AlexisOlson and looping questions: Powerquery has [recursive structures](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-operators#structurally-recursive-operators), and [recursive functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-functions#recursive-functions) although it's often not needed. You can use a regular `for i=0; i < 10; i++) { do stuff }` loop using `List.Numbers(0, 10, 1)` you can do almost anything with [List.Generate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-generate) and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-function-reference

Comment: @ninMonkey Indeed. I use `List.Generate` in the followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488154/power-query-how-to-add-one-to-a-column-when-a-specific-values-appear-in-an-othe/61505574#61505574