# Power Query: how to add one to a column when a specific values appear in an other column

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, increment, powerquery, m

I have an ID column and I am looking for ways to increment my IDs each time a specific item appears in my `Geography` column (`ItalyZ`, `ItalyM`, `UKY` or `UKM`) is found.

The ID of `ItalyZ` starts at 0 and ends at 4000.

The ID of `ItalyB` starts at 4000 and ends at 8000.

The ID of `UKY` starts at 0 and ends at 4000.

The ID of `UKM` starts at 4000 and ends at 8000.

However, I am refreshing my file, and I will thus have from time to time new arrivals of "geographies" without the origins or first IDs. These boundaries/ranges are only known beginning and ends.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
  |---------------------|------------------|    
  |       ID            |   Geography      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    AB0000           |      ItalyZ      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    AB4041           |      ItalyB      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    BC0000           |      UKY         |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    BC4001           |      UKM         |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    NULL             |      ItalyZ      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    NULL             |      ItalyZ      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    NULL             |      UKY         |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    NULL             |      UKM         |
  |---------------------|------------------|
```

Here is my expected output :

```
  |---------------------|------------------|    
  |       ID            |   Geography      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    AB0000           |      ItalyZ      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    AB4041           |      ItalyB      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    BC0000           |      UKY         |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    BC4001           |      UKM         |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    AB0001           |      ItalyZ      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    AB0001           |      ItalyZ      |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    AB4042           |      UKY         |
  |---------------------|------------------|
  |    BC0001           |      UKM         |
  |---------------------|------------------|
```

I have been trying many various ways and trying to adapt running total solutions. I have also been trying to break apart my file in four different ones in order not to have an If function alternating between cases, and thus making it simpler, like this in my power query:

```
 #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Sum", each if [Geography] = "UKM" then [Number AB range below 4000] + 1 
else if [Geography] = "UKY" then [Number AB range above 4000] + 1 
else if [Geography] = "ItalyB" then [Number BC range above 5000]
else [Number BC range below 5000] + 1)
```

But absolutely nothing works. This maddening.

Comment: Constantly posting then deleting variants of the same question over and over is not a nice thing to do

Comment: I am sorry. I realised that it was poorly formulated. I will update and return to the original afterwards. But I am indeed trying to finally completely and absolutely understand conditional count/sums in power query. I would like to be able to absolutely understand it. Is there a way to re-update a question in a thread? For example if the strategy is to formulate and look exhaustively all potential solutions to an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in my other answer, here's a simplified problem ignoring the `ID` letter prefixes you have.

```
ID,  Group | NewID
-----------|------
4,     A   | 4
7,     A   | 7
300,   B   | 300
525,   C   | 525
null,  A   | 10
9,     A   | 9
null,  A   | 11
null,  B   | 301
null,  C   | 526
null,  A   | 12
null,  B   | 302
```

Starting from the left part of the table, we want to compute the new column `NewID`.

In this answer, I will write a custom function that's written recursively using the [List.Generate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-generate) function.

From the linked documentation the function is set up like this

```
List.Generate(
    initial as function,                    /*Set all your initial variables*/
    condition as function,                  /*Stopping criteria.*/
    next as function,                       /*Define how to update at each step.*/
    optional selector as nullable function  /*Pick output element.*/
) as list
```

Define a function that takes a column potentially containing nulls and fills the nulls incrementally from the maximal non-null value:

```
(Column as list) as list =>
let
    Generate =
    List.Generate(
        () => [x = Column{0}, i = 0, n = List.Max(Column)],
        each [i] < List.Count(Column),
        each [
            i = [i] + 1,
            x = if Column{i} = null then [n] + 1 else Column{i},
            n = if Column{i} = null then [n] + 1 else [n]
            ],     
        each [x]
    )
in
    Generate
```

When you define the function, it looks like this and can be re-used in any other queries:

[image: Screenshot]

You can use it by choosing an existing column in an existing table and clicking the Invoke button.

[image: Select Column]

This will create a new list in your Queries pane named Invoked Function that is that function applied to the column you selected.

[image: Invoked Function]

You can also create a blank query and pass it a list. For example, `FilterNulls({4,7,null,9,null,null})` returns `{4,7,10,9,11,12}`.

Here's what that looks like in the query editor.

[image: New Query]

---

What we really want to do is use this function as a column transformation in a group by operation and then expand:

```
let
    Source = <Data Table Source Here>,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Group"}, {{"FillNulls", each FillNulls([ID]), type list}}),
    #"Expanded FillNulls" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "FillNulls")
in
    #"Expanded FillNulls"
```

Here's what it looks like after grouping but before expanding:

[image: Group By]

Notice what the function is doing. We're applying the function `FillNulls` on the `ID` column for each separate `Group`.

---

This is a similar amount of steps and complexity as the other answer but uses a function that is constructed in a recursive way that may be more familiar to you.

Comment: Again, I cannot thank you enough. I am unable to understand yet however. I also do not the simpler option, with fewer steps (no group by, expand, or merge).

Comment: Thank you again.  I am still sadly not getting it...I understand the function construct, but when I try to test and adapt and play around I get "fx" which appears in Power BI asking me to input specific parameters....

Comment: That's correct. You use that function inside your actual query as I specified. The nice part is that it can be used in multiple queries. You may need to change that query to use `fx` instead of `FillNulls` if that's what you named your function.

Comment: As if I add an actual excel function that I can call anywhere? One I will finally be able to make it work it will be great. For now I do not understand because the whole PBI table "becomes" a function with a small hole in which I have to input a parameter which is always rejected...but thank you again.

Comment: Yes, similar to an Excel user-defined function. The parameter it expects is a list. If you define the function `fx` as above, you can call it in a new query by writing e.g. `fx({1,null,2})` or `fx(ExistingTableName[IndexColumn])` putting a list, e.g. a table column, in the "hole" to "invoke" the function on that list.

Comment: Again, thank you! I am going to test this right now and try to make it work with the help of the screenshots. Sorry for not getting it more quickly. On the other hand, I wonder which of the three solutions is optimal and, which is "the best for Power Query". My intuition tells me that the worst is the first with the expand and group...but I have noticed no difference between the two tested solutions, at least to my naked eye...Thank you again! I also notice that "i = 0" is like a dim as integer and "n = List.Max(Column)" is comparable to an array in VBA.

Comment: This one and the simple version in the other answer should be similar. The more complex one in the other answer (with no grouping, expanding, or merging) may be inefficient for large tables since it's calculating a group subtable for each row rather than just for each distinct group.

Comment: Thank you again! ´This is really inspiring. I am know trying to be extremely radical with functions! I am trying to get even more general in the principle and assuming that the highest ID are based in specific file of a PBI and incrementing a Group column in other file/table. I am looking at it with your function and the following: List.Count(List.FindText(Source[Column1], [Column2]))

Answer (score 4):

I will answer a further simplified problem as I don't want to address the `ID` letter prefixes.

Let's say we have the following table (I've included :

```
ID,  Group
-----------
0,     A
1,     A
300,   B
525,   C
null,  A
null,  B
null,  B
null,  C
```

And want to generate a new column `NewID` that will replace `ID`.

```
ID,  Group, NewID
------------------
0,     A,   0
1,     A,   1
300,   B,   300
525,   C,   525
null,  A,   2
null,  B,   301
null,  B,   302
null,  C,   526
```

Here's a method that uses `Table.AddIndexColumn`:

```
let
    Source = <First Table Above>,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Group"}, {{"ID", each List.Max([ID]), type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", (C) => Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.SelectRows(Source, each _[Group] = C[Group]),"NewID",C[ID],1)),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"NewID"}, {"NewID"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"ID"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

First, we group by `Group` to find the maximal `ID` per `Group`:

[image: Group By]

Then we add a new column where each row in the column is a *table* defined by filtering the original table down to just the current group and then adding an index column starting at the maximal `ID` we just found. This is the most complex step.

[image: Add table column]

From here, we expand the `Custom` table column (choosing the column we don't already have) and remove the old `ID` column. We're now where we need to be short of any sorting or column typing we choose to do.

[image: Final]

---

**Edit:** I've made a mistake in the above. Note that the `NewID` for `Group` A is `1,2,3` instead of `0,1,2` I was trying for.

To fix this for this simple example, you can use `List.Min` instead of `List.Max` in the group-by step.

For a more complex example, you may need to add an index column to the source table so you can merge back to it after expanding and only use the new `NewID` for previously null `ID` values since we can't guarantee they are contiguous.

Here's the code:

```
let
    Source = <First Table Above>,
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Group"}, {{"ID", each List.Max([ID]), type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", (C) => Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.SelectRows(Table.Sort(#"Added Index",{"ID"}), each _[Group] = C[Group]),"NewID",C[ID]+1,1)),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Index", "NewID"}, {"Index", "NewID"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, #"Expanded Custom", {"Index"}, "Expanded Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Expanded Custom", {"NewID"}, {"NewID"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Expanded Custom", "ReplaceID", each if [ID] = null then [NewID] else [ID]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"ID", "NewID"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

The complex step changes just a bit:

```
(C) => Table.AddIndexColumn(
           Table.SelectRows(
               Table.Sort(#"Added Index", {"ID"}),
               each _[Group] = C[Group]
           ),
           "NewID", C[ID] + 1, 1
       )
```

The difference is that we need to add a sort so the nulls come after all the already assigned `ID` values and start indexing the nulls at `C[ID] + 1` instead of just `C[ID]`.

---

Here's a version that has fewer steps (no group by, expand, or merge) but a bit more complicated function:

```
let
    Source = <First Table Above>,    
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", (C) => Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each _[Group] = C[Group])),
    #"Added NewID" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "NewID", (C) => if C[ID] = null then Table.SelectRows(Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.SelectRows(C[Custom], each _[ID] = null), "NewID", List.Max(C[Custom][ID])+1,1), each _[Index] = C[Index]){0}[NewID] else C[ID]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added NewID",{"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

The first added `Custom` column is just the indexed source table filtered to the current `Group`. Then we add the `NewID` column defined as:

(Read from the inside out.)

```
(C) =>
  if C[ID] = null
  then Table.SelectRows(
           Table.AddIndexColumn(
               Table.SelectRows(C[Custom], each _[ID] = null),
               "NewID", List.Max(C[Custom][ID]) + 1, 1
           ),
           each _[Index] = C[Index]
       ){0}[NewID]
  else C[ID]
```

Similar to before, we take the group subtable `Custom`, just pick the null `ID` rows and index them starting from the max non-null `ID` plus one. This still leaves us with a table, so we just want the row in this subtable that corresponds to the `Index` from the whole table. We use `{0}[NewID]` to extract the value from the cell in the first (only) row in the table in the `[NewID]` column. For non-null `ID` values, the else clause just leaves them as they were.

Comment: Hi, I thank you extremely strongly. I am a bit depressed because it is complex for me. I thus ask: is this actually really complex? I am trying to understand it. (1) You first add an Index, then you group rows with the max (It thus generates a new table with the max), (2) you then expand the column and (3) merge it with the first table, with only the matching value (left outer) ? (4) finally you add a column which replaces "ID" in certain condition (why?). I am sorry for my questions...

Comment: (1) ✓ (2) ✓ (3) It's a one-to-one match. Inner join would work too. (4) We only replace the null `ID` values in the original table in case the existing `ID` values were not sequential. If they are sequential or you don't need to preserve the original `ID`, then you can use the first simpler approach (with min instead of max).

Comment: You may prefer the alternate formulation with fewer steps I just edited in.

Comment: Thank you again. However, I am still a bit struggling to understand these steps, and above all why it is so much more painfull than in excel to do this. I have tried to read resources and understand the reasons...I am sure there are good reasons...but I am struggling. I understand that this setup of M enables more security and quality...I have also read that this causes some slow performances for PBI, for larger dataset... This is horrible for me. I wish could really understand this.